# Recommendation Engine and Text Analytics

Tags: text-mining, recommender-system

I am looking for a dataset on which I can  use Collaborative filtering and Content based filtering along with Text Mining. 
Could anybody please suggest , is there any dataset on which I can apply both techniques along with Text Mining.